# Map printing using ArcGIS silverlight API

Tags: arcgis-server, printing, arcgis-silverlight-api, geoprocessing-service

I am using a GP task to print my map and its legend. Well it works fine. But it is really slow.

Also I am not able to print the route event layer that I create. It does not show on the map.

Please suggest me an efficient way of printing the map from client side.

I am using ArcGIS 10 Server with Silverlight API on Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Which version of the ArcGIS Silverlight API are you using?

Comment: Where does the GP print task comes from? Is it an Esri built-in task?

Comment: @SethP. I am using ArcGIS 10 with ArcGIS Silverlight 2.2 API (Silverlight 4)

Comment: @PetrKrebs GP task is a Geo-processing Task of ArcGIS Refer(http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/help/index.html#//01660000000n000000)

Comment: Of course, but you are refering to a print task specifically. Which one is that? Is it a built-in Esri GP tool or is it third-party?. Because, as far as I know, server printing (implemented via a GP tool) is included as of 10.1.

Comment: @PetrKrebs Yes you are right GP task is in-built in ESRI, but what I am looking for is a more cheaper way of printing the map without going to the server and doing it in the client  side itself