# Need steps to print a Map in ArcGIS Silveright

Tags: arcgis-silverlight-api, printing

I want to know how to print a map in ArcGIS Silverlight application.

Comment: Please check http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25916/map-printing-using-arcgis-silverlight-api

Comment: i just need the steps to print map in silverlight

Comment: check out following link http://anandganesh2005.blogspot.in/2011/01/arcgis-silverlight-api-printing-with.html

Comment: really it's very good, i saw it before but it just has the code i need the steps or the idea of Printing  to follow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually i found a good video  about advanced topics including [printing map]

http://video.esri.com/watch/1203/advanced-development-with-arcgis-api-for-silverlight

Answer (score 1):

According to your question following will be the steps :

1) Create a new 'MapPrinterViewModel' class

2) Add two properties of type IEnumerable (lets say Graphics1 and Graphics2)

3) Initialize the MapPrinter.DataContext with an instance of this class

4) When it's ready, initialize Graphics1 and Graphics2 with the list of graphics that you want to see in your datagrid 1 and 2.

5) In your MapPrinter control template, bind the ItemsSource of your 2 datagrids to these 2 properties.

For Detail explanation check out [ESRI forum link](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/24560-Printing-map-and-text-in-Silverlight)